# Access SQL query update calculation for duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that filters results for products which have had orders sent after an user-input date, and calculates what the quantity becomes if the order was sent after that date.

```
SELECT *, [OnHand]+[OrderJoin.Quantity] AS Qty After
FROM Query3
WHERE (((Query3.ShippedDate)>[Enter End Date] And (Query3.ShippedDate) Is Not Null));
```

However, I need a way for it to recognise duplicates and update it based on those.

e.g. I have this

```
ID  | Product Name | Qty Before | Qty Shipped | Qty After
11  | Chocolate    |         80 |          20 |       100
11  | Chocolate    |         80 |          10 |        90
```

And I'd need a way for it to show Qty After as 110 (after the 10 and 20 shipped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want an aggregation query.  This would be something like this:

```
SELECT id, ProductName,
       OnHand]+ SUM([OrderJoin.Quantity]) AS Qty After
FROM Query3
WHERE Query3.ShippedDate > [Enter End Date] And
      Query3.ShippedDate) Is Not Null
GROUP BY id, ProductName, OnHand;
```

I note that `OrderJoin` is not defined, but that is the structure of your original query.

Comment: If I remove the WHERE clause to show the whole inventory, do you know how I would make Qty After show as Qty Before, rather than NULL?

Comment: @cfleming93 . . . Perhaps that should be asked as another question.